# add sweet alert angular js

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to use sweet alert plugin from https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert , I already added the corresponding scripts to my index.html like this :

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular-sweetalert/SweetAlert.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

As the documentacion says. Now in my **ctrl.js** I have this :

```
var ctrl = function ($scope, SweetAlert) {

    SweetAlert.swal("Here's a message"); // this does not work
}

ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert];

angular.module('myApp.missolicitudes.controllers',
    [
       'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'
    ])
    .controller('MiSolicitudCtrl', ctrl);
```

But is not working, on my browser I got this error from developer tools:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=oitozero.ngSweetAlertProvider%20%3C-""itozero.ngSweetAlert%20%3C-%20MiSolicitudCtrl
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
>       at http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:40:375
>       at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:364)
>       at http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:40:449
>       at d (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:364)
>       at e (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:124)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:273)
>       at $get (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:80:228)
>       at link (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular-route.min.js:7:268)

How can I implement this plugin correctly?

**Update 1**

I have already try this suggestion by @Pankaj Parkar and @Mike G

```
ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'];
```

and like this

```
ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'SweetAlert'];
```

My developer tools throws this message:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=oitozero.ngSweetAlertProvider%20%3C-"<div class="container ng-scope" ng-view="">"itozero.ngSweetAlert%20%3C-%20MiSolicitudCtrl
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
at http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:40:375
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:364)
at http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:40:449
at d (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:364)
at e (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:124)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:273)
at $get (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js:80:228)
at link (http://localhost:8081/assets/libs/angular/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple module that I wrote to make SweetAlert work.

```
 // sweetalert.js

 angular
  .module('sweetalert', [])
  .factory('swal', SweetAlert);

function SweetAlert() {
  return window.swal;
};
```

Hence, no need to use any other library to use sweetalert, simply write your own.

Simply inject the module in the controller where you want to use it.

**Example**

```
angular
  .module('demo', ['sweetalert'])
  .controller('DemoController', DemoController);

function DemoController($scope) {
  $scope.btnClickHandler = function() {
    swal('Hello, World!');
  };
};
```

Here is an example gist in coffeescript: https://gist.github.com/pranav7/d075f7cd8263159cf36a

Answer (score 2):

I got it work, by **NOT** injecting it in the module.

my **ctrl.js** just got like this

```
ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

and inside my controller y just call it like this

```
var ctrl = function ($scope) {
    swal("Here's a message");
}
```

And it works!, i dont know if the correct way... but at least works.

Comment: its pure jQuery version.. If you wanted to make your code working you could look at mine answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32104508/2435473 which will give you idea how it works..

Answer (score 1):

Never inject a `module` into to `controller` as dependency. You should inject `SweetAlert` factory there which has various function to show alerts. Also add the missing `'` qoute on the factory injection.

You should use

```
ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'SweetAlert'];//<==`oitozero.ngSweetAlert` module               
                                            //could be injectable inside your app module.
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GjfVNXcFWm7Xag126t8B?p=preview)

Comment: @LuisFelipeGarcia could you looked at my updated answer..which has working plunkr too

Answer (score 1):

Inject **sweetalert.min.js** and **sweetalert.css**.
Used like this code in your controller

```
swal({
        type: "error",
        title: "Error!",
        text: "fail",
        confirmButtonText: "OK"
      });
```

`