# Is there any way to combine angular js confirm and sweet alert(swal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sweetalert

In my current project, for logout I want to add confirmation. For the confirmation I want sweet alert. I found solution for confirmation and sweet alert separately but I am finding it difficult to combine those two.
HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="Logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
```

js:

```
app.controller('LogoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'localStorageService', function($scope, $location, localStorageService) {
    $scope.Logout = function() {
        swal({
                title: "Are you sure to logout?",
                text: "",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                cancelButtonText: "No",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            },
            function(isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    localStorageService.clearAll();
        $location.path('/login');

                }
            });
    }
}]);
```

I know there can't be function inside another function but I can't find other way round.
Instead of angular confirm I want to use sweet alert. Is it possible.
Thanks in advance.

[Code in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fb6ptEWbkfRq28LjVnPJ?p=preview)

Comment: this is what you need https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert

Comment: @Vanojx1 .. Yes, I have it. My problem is I am not able to bind that sweetalert with logout confimation. When user clicks logout I want sweetalert confirmation to popup and only on confirmation logout occurs.

Comment: try adding $scope.$apply() after $location.path('/login').

Comment: @ziaulain ... it's not going inside isConfirm function.

Answer (score 0):

there **can be** a function inside another function in javascript

```
function(){
       function abc(){
       }


       //use abc() as much as you want               
}
```

Comment: I am not  abkle to understand your problem statement ... can you pls be more specific

Comment: Yes I know there can't be another function inside a funciton. I am searching a workaround for it.

Comment: I am using the same. Problem is I can't get angular and swal alert to work on confirmation. When user clicks on logout I want swal alert as confirmation box. Only is user confirms then user be logged out. The problem with my work is there can't be function inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

You have special case, where you are making changes in `location` path without letting angular know that something got change, eventually digest cycle isn't getting fire. You should fire digest cycle manually for making `location` changes to understand by angular router. For running digest cycle you could use `$timeout`(inject inside controller before using it)

```
var ctrl = function($scope, $location,$timeout) {

  swal({
      title: "Are you sure to logout?",
      text: "",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
      cancelButtonText: "No",
      closeOnConfirm: true, //it should be true to close popup on confirm
      closeOnCancel: true  //it should be true to close popup on cancel
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
      if (isConfirm) {
        $timeout(function(){
          localStorageService.clearAll();
          $location.path('/login');          
        });
      }
    });
}
```

[**Code In Action**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1GqxyiWQAPKpNFhR3AjF?p=preview)

---

You could look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32104508/2435473) as well, to implement `swal` alert in angular, which will internally handle digest cycle thing internally.

Comment: ...there is function inside function. Will it work ?

Comment: @samjhanajoshi The function that are there in swal` are callback function, passed to `swal` plugin, 1st is success callback(called on "Ok"), 2nd would cancel callback, it should work

Comment: ok I get you now .. but it's not working. Even I click Yes or No it doesn't enter isConfirm function.

Comment: @samjhanajoshi look at updated answer, it would be more helpful that I had added plunkr which is doing to same thing which you want

Comment: Can you look into my plunker .. It's not going into the funciton of IsConfirm

Comment: @samjhanajoshi because you haven't set up any login route in your example.. check mine plunkr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121605/discussion-between-samjhana-joshi-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: @samjhanajoshi have you looked at it? does that helped you?

Comment: No, it's not working ... isConfirm function isn't working.

Comment: Why don't you compare you code with plunkr.. i think you must have missed something